# JS Embedding gfycat on my site

Tags: javascript, embed

gfycat.com gives the option to embed a GIF on my site using **JS Embed** option.

I get a code like this:

```
<img class='gfyitem' data-id='HighMelodicDairycow' />
```

The problem that I couldn't find any information on the site about the Javascipt code needed to run it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find it on their site either but here's their GitHub repo for embedding on 3rd party sites: https://github.com/gfycat/gfycat.js/tree/master
.

Here are the important parts from the readme:

---

## Script

To get the JS Embed working, you just need to add this after the opening body tag:

```
<script>
  (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://assets.gfycat.com/gfycat.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'gfycat-js'));
</script>
```

When this script runs, any element that has the class, `gfyitem` will be converted to a Gfycat embed.

---

## Available Options

If you are wanting to change the behaviour of the embed, you can add these to the element as a data attribute. (`data-`)

- `data-id`: the Gfycat id (*required*)
- `data-controls`: include controls for pause/speed/etc (*default*: `false`)
- `data-title`: show the title on hover (*default*: `false`)
- `data-autoplay`: automatically start playback on page load (*default*: `true`)
- `data-expand` (**DEPRECATED**, please use `data-responsive`): expand video element to fill the space of its container (*default*: `false`)
- `data-responsive`: expand video element to fill the space of its container (*default*: `false`)
- `data-max-height` (works only together with `data-responsive=true`): set height upper bound for a responsive video
- `data-optimize`: play videos when they're 50% visible, and lazy loads gifs (*default*: `true`)
- `data-gif`: load .gif file instead of video (*default*: `false`)
- `data-hd`: load high quality video (*default*: `true`)
- `data-playback-speed`: set video playback speed, values from the interval [`0.125`, `8`] (*default*: `1`)

I know you this is probably too late to help you but hopefully this helps anyone else that runs into this issue.